# JDBC not working in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `spark 1.3.0` which is provided with `CDH 5.4.0 vm`

I am trying to run the code snippet for running queries on `pyspark` via `JDBC` 
I'm not able to connect using any of them:

```
1) pyspark --driver-class-path /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

2) os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar"
```

In both cases when I run this statement :

```
dept1 = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", url="jdbc_url", dbtable="departments")
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 482, in load
     df = self._ssql_ctx.load(source, joptions)
   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
   line 538, in __call__
   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
   line 300, in get_return_value
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.
 : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DriverQuirks$.get(DriverQuirks.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:679)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the actual JDBC url you are using.

Comment: jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db?user=retail_dba&password=cloudera"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add --jars /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar switch.
Why you do driver class path, you only set the jar to the driver not the workers. --jars sends it to them too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to missing dependencies. Have you thought about using [**redshift-spark**](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#common-problems-and-solutions) instead ?

To connect via redshift-spark, verify that you have these jar files in the spark home directory:

1. spark-redshift_2.10-3.0.0-preview1.jar
2. RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar
3. hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar
4. aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
5. (aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.60.jar) (newer version but not everything worked with it)

Put these jar files in $SPARK_HOME/jars/ and then start spark

```
pyspark --jars $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-redshift_2.10-3.0.0-preview1.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.60.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

(SPARK_HOME should be = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/$SPARK_VERSION/libexec")

This will run Spark with all necessary dependencies. Note that you also need to specify the authentication type 'forward_spark_s3_credentials'=True if you are using awsAccessKeys.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="Connect Spark with Redshift")
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", <ACCESSID>)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", <ACCESSKEY>)

df = sql_context.read \
     .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
     .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://example.coyf2i236wts.eu-central-    1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/agcdb?user=user&password=pwd") \
     .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
     .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials',True) \
     .option("tempdir", "s3n://bucket") \
     .load()
```

Common errors afterwards are:

- Redshift Connection Error: "SSL off"

  - Solution:
    `.option("url", "jdbc:redshift://example.coyf2i236wts.eu-central-    1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/agcdb?user=user&password=pwd?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory")`
- S3 Error: When unloading the data, e.g. after df.show() you get the message: "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

  - Solution: The bucket & cluster must be run within the same region

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

> pyspark --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java.jar --jars "usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar"

Or you can copy your jar file and add it to the spark/jar folder.
Now you can use this Driver